Installing g++-4.9 on Debian 10 (buster)
I have a legacy code that needs g++-4.9 to build. I am on Debian 10 (Buster). Is there a way to install g++-4.9 on Debian 10?
My default gcc and g++ version on the system is 8.3
But I also already have gcc-4.9 installed in my system. But I need to install g++-4.9.
I tried searching for solutions and found some posts telling me to add jessie or xenial to apt list, but other posts cautioned against doing so!
I found another post pointing to installing .deb files, but I could not find the .deb files following the links in those posts.
Any help is really appreciated!
Thanks!

Download and build from source? And what is the reason you need such an old version of the GCC C++ compiler?

If there are no other ways, I will try to build from source... although I have not yet been able to locate the source code for g++-4.9. I found gcc source codes for older versions, but I already have installed gcc-4.9. I need this old version of g++ to build an old version of an already tested and validated software (hundreds of source code files) which I want to for benchmarking and validating a newer code!
